# Determine Which has the higher density the pure liquids or solutions?

Tags: density

What i know that it immensely depends on their individual density, but am not really sure since doing research they was no solid answer. i just want a conformation if what am suggesting is correct.

Comment: For pure liquids and corresponding solutions there is a distinct answer, but I don't see any argumentation from your side. Can you re-formulate your thoughts more clearly?

Comment: well i think, it depends on the density of either one of them. Pure liquids such as water has 1g/ml of density whereas solution (methanol etc..) vary with temperature and pressure that determine their density. Therefore either one could be with higher and lower density. does that make sense?,

Comment: Not really, the question is not about density dependency on conditions, rather on *composition*. Density is essentially mass per volume. Liquid and solution would have approx. same volume, but what about the mass?

Comment: It can be even tricky with similar density of pure liquids and important volumetric effects, at least in some ranges. Water and alcohol might be one  example.  As for determination one needs a cylinder and a scale. "On paper" one need tables or complex simulation. The general meaning of the Q is not so evident to me, if we all agree what density is.

Comment: Also d of water shows T dependency.  But as @andselisk pointed out conditions are not mentioned in your question, that, let apart what I have commented above, is self standing as it is.

Comment: okay thank you, it means the question is therefore no use unless given the conditions right? then we can  predict which has a higher or lower density.